# Ionic menu button cannot be clicked after logging in

Tags: html, typescript, button, ionic-framework

I'm having problems with clicking the button upon taking a test.

Scenario:

Upon Logging in -> the user takes a test and submits -> the user is redirected on the home page. But on my home page i cant click on the "Menu button"

on my Login.ts

```
 if (this.checker == "false" || this.checker == null) {
     this.navCtrl.setRoot(LearnertestPage);
 } else {
     this.navCtrl.setRoot(SplashscreenPage);
 }
```

on my test.ts

in the alert controller, I have this

```
 {
    text: 'Yes',
    handler: data => {
      this.learningStyles.push(
      [
      {style: "Auditory", value: AudioTotal},
      {style: "Logical", value: LogicalTotal},
      {style: "Physical", value: PhysicalTotal},
      {style: "Social", value: SocialTotal},
      {style: "Solitary", value: SolitaryTotal},
      {style: "Visual", value: VisualTotal},
      {style: "Verbal", value: VerbalTotal}]
      );
      this.userChecker.update( this.currentUser, { Checker: 'true' });
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(SplashscreenPage);
    }
  }
```

And lastly on my Splash screen or home :

HTMl:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
<ion-content>
<ion-item style="background-color:#00aced">
  <img src="./assets/img/adapt.png" height="100px" width="350px"/>
</ion-item>
<ion-list>

  <button ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
   <ion-icon name="{{p.icon}}"></ion-icon>&nbsp;{{p.title}}
  </button>

  <button ion-item (click)="doConfirm()">
   <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>&nbsp;Logout
  </button>

</ion-list>
```

on the splashscreen.ts

```
@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  selectedItem: any;
  rootPage: any = ListPage;
  selectedTheme:String;
  icons: string[];
  pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, icon: string }>

constructor(){

// used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: SplashscreenPage, icon: this.icons[0], },
      { title: 'Earth Science', component: LessonPage, icon: this.icons[1] },
      { title: 'Progress', component: ProfilePage, icon: this.icons[2] }

    ];
}


openPage(page) {
// Reset the content nav to have just this page
// we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
this.nav.setRoot(page.component); }
```

I can't seem to click on this button. Hmm. What am I doing wrong? 
[image: I can't seem to click on this button.]

Answer (score 0):

try to custom toggle the menu. add the toggleMenu method to the (click) of the menu button

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

    @Component({...})
    export class MyPage {

     constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) {

     }


     toggleMenu() {
       this.menuCtrl.toggle();
     }

    }
```